# Wrong email being sent for event confirmations

Tags: civievent, drupal, 4.7, system-workflow-messages

Until recently, the correct email was being sent out when someone registered. Recently (I don't know exactly when since I don't get a copy of them), the wrong one started going out. I can't figure out why.

The email template being sent is *Events - Registration Confirmation and Receipt (on-line)*.

It used to be that the text under this was sent out if you registered:

```
    {if $event.confirm_email_text AND (not $isOnWaitlist AND not $isRequireApproval)}
```

Now instead of it sending out that, it's sending out what is under the else that is under that.

What could have caused this? The events do not have a waitlist, nor do they require approval. Occasionally we do have ones that do have either/both of those, but none of the current events do.

Thanks!

EDIT: Sorry, forgot to add that this is CiviCRM 4.7.22 and Drupal. I don't know of any PHP updates, but those things sometimes happen via the hosting company without our knowledge. The last CiviCRM updates should have been done prior to the last time I tested the email process a couple weeks back or so.

Comment: Hi Jenni, it helps if you add the version of CiviCRM you are using. And did you do a recent upgrade of CiviCRM, PHP or the database?

Comment: doesn't help you now but using the Transactional Email extension can be useful in such situations as you get to see what went out - https://github.com/fuzionnz/nz.co.fuzion.transactional

Answer (score 1):

I have just a suggestion for debugging:

1. Enable debugging at `civicrm/admin/setting/debug`.
2. Add the smarty token `{debug  output="html"}` to the workflow message template.
3. Now a dump of all the smarty variables and their values are shown in the email. Better to this on a test instance because you do not want your participants to see this.
4. Examine the values of `$event.confirm_email_text`, `$isOnWaitlist` and `$isRequireApproval`. Maybe this gives some more information.

Comment: I'll try that later. It isn't pulling in the waitlist or requireapproval text, as the text under those doesn't show. There's the text I quoted above, then an else, then the waitlist, then the requireapproval. It's pulling the "else".

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, registration (receipt etc.) emails can be very finicky, one small character "{" out of place and things can go south quickly.

Have you've customized your email language? If so, you can revert to the default email message - don't forget to keep a copy of your customizations - and run a test registration to see if the error still exists.

Comment: We did, but it was working for a couple weeks at least after that. I ran tests after the last changes I made and everything was working.

Comment: Is it a new event registration that the email receipt language is not working properly on or all events?

Comment: It's all of them. They're all using the else instead of what they were using previously.

Comment: No other changes to the events themselves? Do the events have confirmation language set in the online registration section?

Comment: Nope, there were no changes since then - some of these were created well before then. The confirmation language is the same it's always been. I've gotten pulled off to a couple other things, so I just copied the text into the "else" for now so that at least the emails are sending. I've got to refresh the database on the dev site so that I can test out some things there to see what I can find out.

Comment: I'm starting to run out of trouble shooting suggestions for you ;) Just so I know - did you test reverting to the default message to see if it would catch the correct half of the if statement? (which should be the {$event.confirm_email_text|htmlize} text.)

Comment: That's what I'm planning to do on the dev site. I can't do it on the live site since people are actively signing up for things. The band-aid fix works for now, but I want to get it actually fixed. I'm going to reset the dev site to match the live site and then test out all the suggestions. I just hit some other stuff that was more time sensitive and had to switch hats. Isn't that how it always works? ;)